# Python Pandas Query

Tags: pandas

I have below columns in my Pandas Data Frame

```
Loan_ID

Loan_Status - contain ( 'Y' or 'N')

LoanStatus_ridgeClass - contain ('Y' or 'N')
```

I want to filter out Loan `Status ='Y'` and Loan `Status_ridgeClass ='N'` records
Loan

```
0
LP001015 Y Y 

1
LP001022 Y N

2
LP001031 Y N

3
LP001035 Y Y 

4
LP001051 Y Y
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Loan_no =NameOfDataFrame.loc[NameOfDataFrame["LoanStatus_ridgeClass"] == "Y", [ "Loan_ID", "Loan_Status"]]
```

Comment: This is my first post. Let me know if I need to clarify. And let me know if it works.

Comment: This will be useful thanks